# Recurrence relation. Application to ternary sequences

Tags: recurrence-relations, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

The question is:

*How many ternary sequences have no double zero?*

For this I understand that our $n$-digit sequence either have $0,1,\dots,n$ zeroes, is this ok?

If the answer of above is positive, then on the $n$th position we can have either a 1 or a 2, thus $2a_{n-1}$ sequences, no problem here.

However, if the string in the $n$th position there's a zero, then:

$$
\dots 10 \\
\dots 20
$$

and the result claims to be: $a_n = 2(a_{n-1} + a_{n-2})$. However, my problem is the following: **do I have to exclude the cases in the last part where there's a zero somewhere in the previous $n-2$ positions**?

Answer (score 2):

Let $A_n$ denote the total number of "good" strings of length $n$.

Let $B_n$ denote the total number of "good" strings of length $n$ which do not end in $0$

Let $C_n$ denote the total number of "good" strings of length $n$ which end in $0$.

We have: $$A_n=B_n+C_n$$

$$B_n=2B_{n-1}+2C_{n-1}=2A_{n-1}$$

$$C_n=B_{n-1}=2A_{n-2}$$

Combining all this we get $$A_n=2\left(A_{n-1}+A_{n-2}\right)$$

Comment: One question, for $C_n=B_{n-1}$. $B_n$ is a good string that can have either $0,1,\dots,n$ zeroes, right? When you have all the strings with at least one zero somewhere in the $n-1$ positions, putting a zero at the end of the string gives you double zero, is this right?

Comment: Not sure I am following.  I don't care how many zeroes my string has, so long as it doesn't contain two in a row.  To get a string in $C_n$ I have to take a string in $B_{n-1}$ and append a $0$.

Comment: For example the $n-1$ sequence, which is counted in $B_{n-1}$: $\dots01$, if I attach at the end of this string a zero, I am going to have the $n$-length string: $\dots010$, which it should be forbidden.

Comment: Still not sure I am following.  Maybe we are saying the same thing.  If I take a string in $C_n$ and cut the final $0$ off, I get a string in $B_{n-1}$.  That's all I am saying.

Comment: My concern is whether or not a sequence of length $n-1$ (which is counted in $B_{n-1}$) can contain exactly 1 zero. If so, then attaching a zero at the end of the chain will give a double zero, which is forbidden by the problem. This is really my question, not the solution to the problem.

Comment: Perhaps I did not read the question properly.  Are you asking for strings which don't contain more than a single zero?  I thought you wanted strings in which $00$ does not occur.  Thus, for me, $2012011022202120$ is a perfectly good example.

Comment: Ok, if the statement _no double zero_ means that I cannot have a sequence like $120022$, then I understand the solution to the problem. I understand it as $102210$ cannot happen. Thanks for discussing it with me :) )

Comment: No problem.  I'm pretty sure my reading is the intended one (well, it helps that I get the predicted recursion).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38642/discussion-between-user2820579-and-lulu).